# Java - Number of occurrences of a digit in a number without loop

Tags: java, logic, find-occurrences

Given a non-negative int n, how do i return the count of the occurrences of a digit e.g 7, so for example 717 yields 2? (no loops). Here is my code but it doesn't work well.

```
 public int count7(int n) {
int count = 0;
  if(n==7){
  count++;

  return count;
  }
 else if(n>7 && n<100)

  return count7(n/10)+count7(n%10);

  else if( n>100)

  return count7(n/10)+count7(n%10);

  else return 0;

}
```

Comment: to count the number of 7, you have to look at every number to see if that number is a 7. That implies a loop of some sort. Also, what exactly do you mean by `doesn't work well`?

Comment: i am trying to solve it recursively. It only works with smaller integers like e.g 7123 but not with bigger one's like e.g 777576197. I will ask on math overflow then

Comment: your problem with this code is not with large number, it is with number containing `9` or `8`, because of `count7(n%10)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code seems like it should be working. Not sure what you mean by "doesn't work well".
Here is an a bit cleaner/shorter version of the same solution:

```
int count7(int n) {
    if(n == 0) return 0;
    return (n%10 == 7 ? 1 : 0) + count7(n/10);
}
```

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly. Mine wasn't working for bigger values. I was getting a stackoverflow error.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's not because of "bigger values", it's because of this piece: `else if(n>7 && n<100) return count7(n/10)+count7(n%10);`. Suppose, `n == 8`. Then `n%10` is also 8, and you will keep recursing infinitely. So, you'll get this error with any number, containing 8 or 9, not necessarily a large one. Even just `8` will do. 
Replace `7` with `9` in the condition if you want to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

For the fun of it:

```
  public static int count7( int n ) {
    return Integer.toString( n )
                  .replaceAll( "[^7]" , "" )
                  .length();
  }
```

Probably better fits to code golf ,-)

Answer (score 0):

A fast solution :

```
return Integer.toString(n).split("7").length-1;
```

When you want to look at the digits in the decimal representation of a number, it's usually reasonable to let the already available and optimized number stringification function do the job (that is `Integer.toString(yournumber)`). Of course there are loops behind, but there's even loops in the implementation of your recursive calls...

Comment: Doesn't work for me when the digit starts or ends with the integer you are splitting on. `"725672".split("7")` returns `["256","2"]`. `length-1` will return `1`. The answer is 2.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution :

```
public int count(int number, int digit){
    String numberToString = new Integer(number).toString();
    String digitToString = new Integer(digit).toString();
    return StringUtils.countMatches(numberToString,digitToString);
}
```

It will count for you how many `digit` are in `number`

So `count(717,7)` will return `2`